# Bash script: subtract prefix from string

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm running some code whereby I attempt to subtract a prefix from a string.

When I run the following script, $prefix and $whole appear as desired.

```
prefix=${dir/*\/};
whole=${f2%.mp3};
echo "$prefix";
echo "$whole";
```

However, when I run the following I get a "bad substitution" error on the line where I define $final.

```
prefix=${dir/*\/};
whole=${f2%.mp3};
final=${$whole#$prefix};
echo "$final";
```

Something must be wrong with my syntax. I've fiddled with it a bit with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: syntax...I meant

Comment: Luckily, this problem was not hard to solve.   But you should try to make your question(s) easier to solve by making them easier to understand.   As one of the answers said, you should show sample input and expected output, and maybe explain the steps you are doing in a little bit more detail.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you left one `$` too much. Replace `$whole` to:

```
final=${whole#$prefix};
```

Comment: Woohoo! Thank you, thank you, thank you! :D